# How to import variables from one method to another, and from one secondary method to a different method in a differenc class?

Tags: java, methods

I'm building a program in a console, and the script structure I'm trying to do is:

```
main class
    main methodclass
Secondary class 1
    main methodclass1
    secondary methodclass1
Secondary class 2
    main methodclass2
    secondary methodclass2
    secondary2 methodclass2
```

And so on. The goal is that by the end, I just need to call the other classes on the main class, and the same regarding secondary classes. The main method on the secondary class just calls other methods. This is what I have

```
class GameEngine {                          // this is a secondary class

     public static void main(String args) {   //main method from secondary class
     GameEngine.CommandLine(command);  //

}
```

and then a class:

```
final static void CommandLine(String command) {   //secondary method from secondary class

    command = Console.nextLine(3);}
```

And I already have another piece of code, which is under CommandLine(String command), but I wanted to place it under another method. This code treats command and converts into coordinates.

Now, how can I call the variable 'command' from the Secondary Method 1 (CommandLine) to the Secondary Method 2 (NamePending)? And how do I call both methods to the main method?

And, now that we're at it, I am currently able to run the program by calling in the main class the secondary class `GameEngine.main(args);`, I'm also able to call variables from other main classes such as the class Settings, for example : `Console.cursor((Settings.pcy),(Settings.pcx));`
How do I do the same if the class has several methods?

Comment: Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) tutorial. :)

Comment: Is that the only way? I thought about using that, but I wanted to keep a Structured Program to make it easier to read and keep track of